# Selenium: Element not clickable at point (x, y)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this site https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2017 where I want my script to insert a number in PAGE field and click GO, but I keep getting error:

```
File "/Users/anhvangiang/Desktop/PY/inc.py", line 34, in scrape
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-input-button"]').click()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Element is not clickable at point (741, 697)
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 
(c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

This is my code:

```
def scrape(num):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/anhvangiang/Desktop/PY/chromedriver')
    driver.get(main_site)
    driver.find_element_by_id('page-input-field').send_keys(str(num))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Welcome-59"]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-input-button"]').click()
    soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    container = soup.find('section', {'id': 'data-container'})
    return [source + tag.find('div', {'class': 'col i5 company'}).find('a')['href'] for tag in container.findAll('div', {'class': 'row'})]
```

If I put the function scrape inside a loop:

```
 for i in range(1, 100):
     print scrape(i)
```

For a few first i, it will go smoothly, but then it will throw the error like above.

Any suggestion how I can fix it?

Comment: The element that you are trying to click is on the browser view? If not scroll it and try again.

Comment: @santhoshkumar I will try to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the button is not visible at that time, so the selenium WebDriver cannot access that.
As I run your code on my local machine , I found that the website shows a popup ad for 15-20 sec (See attached image : [Popup_Ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5OaQ.png)), which is the actual cause of this error. For resolving this error you have to handle the popup ad, you can do this as.

> check for the SKIP button, if button exist then first skip the add by
>   Clicking the skip button , then follow the normal flow of code.

**Other Suggestions:** You should use **WebDriverWait** to avoid the *Element not found* and *element is not clickable* like issues. For Example, you can write above code as

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
import time

def scrape(num,wdriver):
    # define webdriver 
    driver = wdriver

    # naviagte to url
    driver.get("https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2017")

    # define default wait time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    while True:
        if EC.presence_of_all_elements_located:
            break
        else:
            continue

    # handle Ad Popup
    try:
        skip_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='Welcome-59']/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]")))
        skip_button.click()
        print("\nSkip Button Clicked")
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    time.sleep(5)
    # find the page number input field

    page_num_elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"page-input-field")))
    page_num_elem.clear()
    page_num_elem.send_keys(num)
    time.sleep(2)

    while True:
        try:
            # find go button
            go_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "page-input-button")))
            go_button.click()
            break
        except TimeoutException :
            print("Retrying...")
            continue

    # scrape data
    soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    container = soup.find('section', {'id': 'data-container'})
    return [tag.find('div', {'class': 'col i5 company'}).find('a')['href'] for tag in container.findAll('div', {'class': 'row'})]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create webdriver instance
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for num in range(5):
        print("\nPage Number : %s" % (num+1))
        print(scrape(num,driver))
        print(90*"-")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you show me how to press the SKIP button because i tried but it didnt work

Comment: See the edited answer for the full source code. 
Some Tips: 
      1] Do remember that, WebDriver cannot perform button click until the DOM finish loading, if it didn't then this may lead to Button Not Clickable exception.
      2] Avoid handling pagination this way, try to utilize the pager (next / previous buttons).
      3] Use Exception Handling to avoid unexpected termination of program.
      4]  Don't Go Too Fast , wait after filing-up the input fields, at least for 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: For some reason, the clicking the skip button only open new window and doesnt close the pop up ad.

Comment: @V.Anh , yes the skip button is not functioning the same anymore, but you can still use the above given script, it works fine (tested), it may be little bit slow due to many time.sleep(n) but working fine. As of now, for handling this popup, waiting is the only solution,because disabling JavaScript may create more problems (like pagination stopped working, Go button will not work etc.)  Always remember one thing that, in Web Scraping , your script may stop working at any moment since it is totally dependent on the website source code.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me:

Actions action = new Actions(Browser.WebDriver);                    action.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();

Comment: I tried that, this is my code                                                           
    `go_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-input-button"]'))) 
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(go_button).click().perform()` But it wouldnt click the element.

Comment: I put the go_button inside the click function then it worked but it wouldnt click if an ad appears on the site.

Comment: It relates to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1852. Maybe downgrade your chrome version.